# Debugging pure method chain

Tags: debugging, haskell

Hello i want to ask fellow haskellers how can you debug haskell programs efficiently if you have a long chain of pure methods.E.g:

```
do
  a<-impure
  (pure a)  # where pure calls pure1->pure2->pure2
```

How can i debug anything deep in the call stack if everything is not `IO` ,therefore i can't `print` or `writeFile` anywhere without significant effort ?
Do haskell fellows just change all signatures to `IO something` to see where the code crashes?

**Concrete example**

**Main**

```
module Main where 
    import Data.Text(Text,pack,unpack)
    import Data.Text.IO(readFile,writeFile)
    import TCPFile(TCPFile)
    import TCPEncoding(toText,fromText)
    main::IO()
    main=do
        dat<-readTcpFile "test.txt"
        print dat
        writeTcpFile "output.txt" dat

    writeTcpFile::FilePath->TCPFile->IO()
    writeTcpFile path file=Data.Text.IO.writeFile path (toText file)

    readTcpFile::FilePath->IO TCPFile
    readTcpFile path =fromText <$> Data.Text.IO.readFile path 


module TCPEncoding where 
import Data.Text
class TextEncode a where
    toText::a-> Text
    fromText::Text-> a
```

I will not write the whole hierarchy of methods.I just want to know how can i run the program until a certain line and get the variable values and the stack frame.

In the case of this program all i get at the end written in my file with `writeTcpFile`is:

`main: <<loop>>`
So how can i debug the `fromText` method  used inside `readTcpFile` and its internals?

Comment: You can use `trace` from `Debug.Trace` to print satements when something is evaluated.

Comment: Here's how I usually go about understanding how pure functions work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48222438/126014

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use [trace](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.17/base-4.11.1.0/Debug-Trace.html#v:trace) as previously mentioned

`trace :: String -> a -> a` so it take a `String` and the value and returns the same value like `id`. It will be triggered at the point you want to use it, so for you:

```
main = do
  dat <- readTcpFile "test.txt"
  _ <- trace "write what you want to see in console" dat
  writeTcpFile "output.txt" dat
```

if you want to trace the value of `dat` you have to make sure to convert it to a `String`.
Also inside the do block it's been bound to `_` so it doesn't do any side effects.