# How to step through a Quickcheck process

Tags: haskell

I have the follow two functions:

```
leftPoint :: Point -> Board -> Point
rightPoint :: Point -> Board -> Point
```

It should have the propoerty:

```
rightPoint (leftPoint p b) b == p
```

Or in English: the right point of a point's left point is itself.

My test failed with a case but I'd like to run through the test in a step by step way to understand it.
Does Haskell or QuickCheck library provide such a debugging tool?

Comment: Should `rightPoint (leftPoint p b) b == p`? Now you basically say that the right point of the left point of `p` is the left point of `p`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks for point this out.my bad, it's a typo. In my program it's correct without this typo.

Comment: QuickCheck will usually report the value(s) that caused the property to be falsified. Doesn't it do that for you?

Comment: @MarkSeemann it does and it certainly helps. but sitll I prefer to see the exact failure location.

Comment: If Haskell comes with a debugger that enables you step through code, I'm not aware of it. I usually troubleshoot Haskell code like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48222438/126014