# Why is the result of my foldr call on an empty list not in the correct order?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fold

I'm trying to complete problem 8 of the Haskell Ninety-Nine problems however I'm having issues understanding why the list result of my function is ordered wrong.

The aim of the `compress` function is to eliminate any duplicate letters from the input list and output another list that contains the unique letters in the order in which they first appear in the input list.
Here is my code for the compress function:

```
compress l = foldr f [] l where f a b = if a `elem` b then b else a : b
```

It functions correctly when the duplicate letters are adjacent to each other hence "aaaabbb" outputs "ab" which is correct however when a duplicate letter is separated by another letter it changes its order in the output hence "aba" outputs "ba" whereas the expected output is "ab".

Even when writing out the stack trace for foldr I seem to get the expected output however when running the code in the GHCI with an input such as "aba" or "abca" I get the incorrect result. What causes this behaviour? Why is it that when a duplicate letter is separated by a different letter the order of the output is changed?

Comment: `b` is the result of the *tail* being folded, so ``a `elem` b`` is only false for the *last* occurrence of `a` in the string. With `"aaaabbb"`, it's still the last occurrence of each character being added to the result; the last occurrence just happens to be in the same "cluster" as the first.

Comment: An inefficient *left* fold that works would be `compress = foldl (\acc x -> if elem x acc then acc else acc ++ [x]) []`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172004/writing-foldl-using-foldr for converting `compress` from `foldl` to `foldr`.

Comment: @chepner, while that technique is the right technique, that code is not the right code. The thing to do here is to start by writing an efficient function (using a recursive helper) and then converting *that* to a (right) fold. `foldl` has the wrong shape to do this well.

Comment: Part of the reason I posted the "wrong" code is to avoid writing the correct one for the OP. It was just to demonstrate working on the right "end" of the list.

Comment: There is this [old SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3100764/11282404) about the elimination of duplicates in a list. And if the rules of the game ban the use of `Set` or you have no `Ord` instance, you can always use another list as the computation state instead of the Set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `foldr` function starts with an initial value (of the type `b`) and a `Foldable` container `t`. For 'each' `a` value in the container, it calls the function `(a -> b -> b)` with the `a` value and the 'current' `b` value.

```
Prelude> :t foldr
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

In `compress`, the initial value is `[]`, which also enables the compiler to infer that the `Foldable` instance is `[]`.

Now try out the steps in GHCi. Define (just for the GHCi session) `f` as a top-level function:

```
Prelude> f a b = if a `elem` b then b else a : b
```

If the input is `"aba"`, the first time `f` is called, the `b` value will be `[]` and the `a` value will be `'a'`, because `foldr` folds from the right.

```
Prelude> f 'a' []
"a"
```

The return value `"a"` now becomes the accumulator value `b` for the next time around:

```
Prelude> f 'b' "a"
"ba"
```

This is because `f` conses `'b'` onto `"a"`.

The accumulator value is now `"ba"`. Pass it to `f` again, using the third and final value in the list:

```
Prelude> f 'a' "ba"
"ba"
```

See e.g. [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48222438/126014) that outlines an interactive way to explore and 'debug' Haskell functions.

Comment: It's funny. "Third and final" is definitely idiomatic, but in this case it might be a bit misleading. It's temporally final but semantically initial -- it's the first element of the list that's being folded! Especially the continuation "final value in the list" makes it seem like the semantic interpretation is intended.

Comment: @DanielWagner You're right. I was thinking of the order of evaluation of the elements when I wrote that.

Comment: The `Foldable` instance is `[]`, not `[] Char`. I know what you mean by that statement, but the OP probably won't grok your shorthand.

Comment: @dfeuer Well, that I can edit (edited).

Comment: I see the logic here however how come when the input is changed to "ab" as opposed to "aba" the output is no longer "ba" but instead "ab"? Surely the same steps would follow meaning a would be added first then the cons operator would be applied with b leading to "ba" which should be the final output.

Comment: @Pzet Try walking through the steps of `f` as shown above, but using `"ab"` instead of `"aba"` as the input.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Thank you, I see why this is happening now.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> compress l = foldr f [] l where f a b = if a `elem` b then b else a : b
> ```
>
> *... `"aba"` outputs `"ba"` whereas the expected output is `"ab"`.*

`foldr` on lists is very simple. It is defined so that

```
foldr g z [a,b,c,...,n]  =  g a (foldr g z [b,c,...,n])

-- and by generalization,
foldr g z [          n]  =  g n z

-- which means
foldr g z [           ]  =      z
```

That's really all there is to it. Looks self-explanatory, isn't it? Just re-write your `foldr` call, syntactically, to immediately see *exactly* what's going on. In particular, re-writing your definition a little bit, we have

```
compress xs  =  foldr f [] xs
    where
    f a r  =  if  elem a r  then      r 
                            else  a : r
```

*(I do (try to) always call the second argument to the combining function "**`r`**", for the "**Recursively** calculated **Result** for the **Rest** of the input list".)*

Thus we have

```
compress             [a,b,c,...,n]
   =  foldr f []     [a,b,c,...,n]  
   =  f a ( foldr f [] [b,c,...,n] )
   =  if  elem a r  then      r 
                    else  a : r
        where 
        r = foldr f [] [b,c,...,n]
   =  if  elem a r  then      r 
                    else  a : r
        where 
        r = compress   [b,c,...,n]
```

(using `where` as if it where a part of the expression, like a "flipped `let`"). In  other words,

```
compress (x:xs) = if  elem x   r  
                    then       r
                    else   x : r
                  where        r = compress xs
compress []     = []
```

This reads: *"if `x` is present in the **compressed** rest of input, skip it; else, keep it; and continue with the compressed rest".* <sub>(so, calling it `b` is misleading; suggests `a` and `b` are similar entities; they are *not* -- `a` (or `x`) is an *element* of the list, and `r` is its transformed *tail*).</sub>

So you see where the problem is: if there are more then one `a`s in the list, this definition keeps the *last* one, whereas you want to keep the first.

So if there are several of them in a row this difference is unobservable:

```
       -- 1.                    -- 2.
     a a a a b b b            a a a a b b b
           a     b            a       b
```

but if there's an intervening character then of course we can see the difference:

```
       -- 1.                    -- 2.
     a a a a b b b a          a a a a b b b a
                 b a          a       b
```